# C# and linq in loops

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I have the following loop:

```
foreach (var key in model.AllKeys.Where(k => !k.StartsWith("hdn") && !k.StartsWith("__"))) 
{ 
  var field = form.Fields.Where(f => f.Key.Equals(key));
  formFields.Add(key, model[key]); 
}
```

I was just wondering if the `where` in `model.AllKeys.Where(k => !k.StartsWith("hdn") && !k.StartsWith("__"))` is run once or for each item in the loop as when you step over the code it hits it each time in the loop.

Would it be better to do this:

```
var keys = model.AllKeys.Where(k => !k.StartsWith("hdn") && !k.StartsWith("__"))
foreach (var key in keys) 
{ 
  var field = form.Fields.Where(f => f.Key.Equals(key));
  formFields.Add(key, model[key]); 
}
```

Comment: `Where` is executed once but the inner predicate is evaluated for every item in the source collection `model.AllKeys`.

Comment: It would execute the same way.

Comment: Both should be same

Comment: Ah ok, that's good to know thanks

Comment: You could use a Join to combine the filtered `AllKeys` with the `form.Fields` and iterate only once over the results. This would be cleaner and allow you to optimize each collection separately, eg by changing them into hashsets or dictionaries. You could avoid `formFields.Add` too and convert the results of the single query into a dictionary with `ToDictionary()`